# What shapes can be approximated by iid random variables?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, probability-distributions

We know that if $X_i\sim N(0,1)$, then $(X_1, \dots, X_n)/\sqrt{n} \to \text{Unif}(S^{n-1})$ in distribution.
That is, the uniform distribution on the $n$-dimensional sphere can be approximated by a vector with all entries independent.

Similarly, I believe that $X_i\sim$ Laplace Distribution converges to the uniform distribution on the L1 ball, that is $\{x \in \mathbb R^n : \|x\|_1 = 1\}$. However, I haven't been able to find a reference for this. Maybe it has to be the Cauchy distribution rather than Laplace.

I wonder which other shapes can be approximated in this way?
Maybe shape is the wrong word, since there needs to be an infinite family in progressively higher dimensions.

I assume a necessary condition is symmetry of the coordinates.
Are there well known necessary conditions as well?

Comment: Do you mean the two sided Laplace distribution, or $X_i >0$?

Comment: @user619894 I mean the two-sided exponential distribution

Answer (score 0):

(Not an authoritative answer)

Call $Y={(X_1\cdots X_n)\over \sqrt n}$.

My intuition to whether a r.v.is concentrated on a spherical "shell" is how much the fluctuations are with respect to the mean radius. I believe that for both distributions the behavior is qualitatively the same:

The fluctuations around the mean squared radius are   $<(Y^2 -<Y^2>)^2>=<Y^4-<Y^2>^2>={<X^4>-<X^2>^2\over n}$, whereas the mean radius itself is $<Y^2>=<X^2>$, so that  the standard deviation of the radius $\sqrt{{<X^4>-<X^2>^2\over n}}\sim {1\over \sqrt n}$ which means that for both distributions, the fluctuations get tighter and tighter with $n$.

On the other hand, I don't know what the fluctuations of a large $n$ hypercube shell look like, maybe they also get tighter.

PS: the Cauchy distribution doesn't have a second moment, so the previous argument fails.

Comment: I fear that distributions may be concentrated on some shape, but not actually have the uniform distribution on that same shape?

Comment: I see your point. They are concentrated on the shell, but in clusters.